# How the CSS <div> tag styles applies to the following code

Tags: html, css

This is a CSS styling with  tag. Now i would like to learn how does the styling works with HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Internal CSS</title> 
        <style> 
            .main { 
                text-align:center; 
            } 
            .GFG { 
                color:#009900; 
                font-size:50px; 
                font-weight:bold; 
            } 
            .geeks { 
                font-style:bold; 
                font-size:20px; 
            } 
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div class = "main"> 
        <div class ="GFG">GeeksForGeeks</div> 
        <div class ="geeks">A computer science portal for geeks</p> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

[The image shows the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfMDC.jpg)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: Hi, you have an error in your html, I assume that </p> tag after A computer science portal for geeks should be a </div> instead.

Comment: I think it's asking how the browser renders the html/css in general too broad voted to close.

Comment: Take in account that the valid values for font-style are: normal, italic, oblique and inherit, so in your example the value bold for that style property is invalid. You can check the reference for font-style here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-styling

Answer (score -2):

You should definitely take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp (it's how I learned everything about html that I know now). A brief explanation of how your code works is that you can use create styles like the

```
.GFG { 
            color:#009900; 
            font-size:50px; 
            font-weight:bold; 
}
```

that you copied and you can call them into types of text like

```
<p class = "GFG">Hello World!</p>
```

and they will output with the style that was chosen. Good luck!